# jquery takes away navigation bar

Tags: javascript, jquery

when my sites window size is small (mobile view) and user clicks on hamburger menu I use jquery to fade in the navigation menu.  When I click outside of the navigation its fades the navigation menu out.

if I resize my window larger my navigation bar should resize it self, however it is not even there. I'm guessing because I faded it out with jquery.

I tried make it the script run only if the window size was less than certain size, but navigation menu is still gone when i resize larger.

how can I fix this?

jquery script

```
//fades in
$("#mobileNav").click(function(){

  $(".nav").fadeIn("slow");
  event.stopPropagation();

})


// fade out on click outside of navigation menu
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.nav')) {
    isSmallWindow = $(window).width() < 600;
    if(isSmallWindow) {
      $(".nav").fadeOut("slow");
    }
  }

$(window).resize(function() {

        isBigWindow = $(window).width() > 600;
            if(isBigWindow) {
                            $(".nav").show();
            }
                    });
```

html

```
            <div id="mobileNav" class="mobileNavContainer floatLeft">
                <div class="bar1"></div>
                    <div class="bar2"></div>
                    <div class="bar3"></div>
                </div>

            <div id="para1" class="floatLeft"></div>

            </div>




        <!----------  NAVIGATION  ---------->
        <div class="nav">




                <!-- link icons have custom css - icon -->
                <a href="index.php?page=clients" title="Clients">
                    <span class="navIcon">
                        <i class="fa fa-users icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </span>
                    <span class="navText">
                        Clients
                    </span>
                </a>

                <a href="index.php?page=invoices" title="Invoices">
                    <span class="navIcon">
                        <i class="fas fa-file-invoice icon"></i>
                    </span>
                    <span class="navText">
                        Invoices
                    </span>
                </a>



        </div>
```

Comment: Does this also occur when you resize the page and then reload it?

Comment: You need to add the same function on the windows resize event handler. Like `window.resize = funciton(event) {` 
Also, try to share the HTML of your code by adding a snippet here, it'll be easier for other's to help

Comment: So either fade it in on resize over X size or add style to force it to be visible.

Comment: you could probably do this more reliably with CSS media queries and transitions

Comment: @ADyson issue is element will be hidden via style so means only way around it would be important....

Comment: ok i updated my question with what i used to fix the issue thanks to epascarello.  no my question is how can i take the fade out and have it just appear.  i tried using show() instead of fade, but it still fades in.

Comment: I think you can set `$.fx.off = true;` before you do `$(".nav").show();` (And then set it back to `false` to allow other animations), or try `$(".nav").show( 0 );`

Comment: can you post an example of what you mean....i went with another solution of just toggling a class, but i like the animation factor

Comment: I'm not going to do that because it's a guess rather than a real answer. I also wouldn't do it the way you did, I would use [media queries](https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) for this because it is better performance-wise

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to add a resize event to check if the window is larger than 600 otherwise it will never know when to show the nav again.

```
$(window).on('resize', function(e){
  if($(this).width() > 600 && $('.nav:visible').length == 0){
   $('.nav').fadeIn();
  }
});
```

Comment: i did this and it worked, however i started having other issues and ended up just creating another class and toggle the class.